# How do you resolve Ternary operators with multiple ?'s and :'s in React

Tags: reactjs, operators, ternary

```
{
      this.props.favoriteButton ?
        this.state.favorited ?
          <div className="star">&#9733;</div>
        :
          <div 
            className="star"
            onClick={() => this.favorite(recipe)}
          >
            &#9734;
          </div>
      :
        <div></div>
    }
```

If there are multiple ?'s before proceeding to ternary statement in react does it mean both conditions have to be met meaning true? How does this statement work... Quite confused on this...

Comment: What do you mean? It's basically another syntax for `if (if do-else)-else`

Answer (score 2):

After conversion to simple ifs:

```
if (this.props.favoriteButton) {
    if (this.state.favorited) {
        return <div className="star">&#9733;</div>;
    } else {
        return <div className="star" onClick={() => this.favorite(recipe)}>&#9734;</div>;
    }
} else {
    return <div></div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help & clarification

Answer (score 0):

When the first condition is not met, the second condition doesn't matter

```js
const x = document.getElementById("x")
const y = document.getElementById("y")
const result = document.getElementById("result")
x.addEventListener("change", showResult)
y.addEventListener("change", showResult)

function showResult() {
  return result.textContent =
  x.checked ?
    y.checked ?
      "x and y checked"
      : "x checked, y unchecked"
    : "x unchecked, y whatever"
}

showResult()
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="x"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="y"/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help appreciate it.